# Regarding qlikview dashboard automation with selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using qlikview dashboard for testing. Now I am automating it using selenium . But when try to click on a specific page where the page itself is not like a normal browser page as when u right click on the page u ll see only qlikview options instead of normal browser options. So how to click on that page element.

Since it's a new tab already window handle has been done. Need to click on an element and proceed further.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Right Click